# what does "__requires__" mean in python?

Tags: python, setuptools

I am newbie in python.

Could anybody answer what does `__requires__` means in the following code?
Why would they put `__requires__ = 'flower==0.4.0'` in the beginning of the file?

```
#!/srv/virtualenvs/zeusenv/bin/python

__requires__ = 'flower==0.4.0'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('flower==0.4.0', 'console_scripts', 'flower')()
)
```

Comment: means to run that package you need to have flower to be installed first...

Comment: Why don't they just use "import flower" but "__reuqire__ ...."

Comment: ur system might not have that package so you download the package before you import...

Comment: still a little confuse about it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `__requires__` line is part of a generated console script. It has no meaning to Python itself, only the `setuptools` library uses this information.

Console scripts are python scripts defined in a python package metadata, and `setuptools` installs wrapper script files to let you run them as command line scripts. The `flower` file installed in your virtualenv is such a script, defined by the `flower` package `setup.py` file.

The `pkg_resources` module imported in the wrapper script inspects the value of `__requires__`  in the main script to make sure the correct version of the library is available and loaded before the `load_entry_point` function (or any other `pkg_resources` function) is run. It'll not install the version specified, it is assumed that that version is *already* installed on your system. It's purpose is to avoid loading incorrect, incompatible resources when the script runs and loads dependencies.